# Does we have $\int_{\sum_{i=1}^{\frac{p}{k}}\frac{1}{i}}^{\sum_{i=1}^{p}\frac{1}{i}}e^{-\left(\frac{x}{p}\right)^{p}}dx\to \ln(k)$ as $p\to \infty$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, logarithms, improper-integrals, examples-counterexamples, gamma-function

### Problem/Conjecture  :

Let $p,k,n\in(3,\infty)$ be positive integers such that  $p=kn$ then it seems we have as $p\to \infty$ :

### $$\int_{\sum_{i=1}^{\frac{p}{k}}\frac{1}{i}}^{\sum_{i=1}^{p}\frac{1}{i}}e^{-\left(\frac{x}{p}\right)^{p}}dx\to \ln(k)$$

---

---

I have tried to squeeze the integral with the [Fatou-Lebesgue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%E2%80%93Lebesgue_theorem) theorem but cannot proceed further here .

On the other hand the integral above implies the incomplete Gamma function but again I don't see how to get the logarithm .

It seems also to note this is the discrete case and I think the continued analogue is plausible too .

---

---

Any ideas to (dis)prove it ?

Comment: I think you meant to use $n$ as the summation index not $i$ ? Or perhaps the other way around? You are mixing your metaphors i think

Comment: @K.defaoite Thanks I'm bit tired sorry for the confusion .

Comment: The integral is equal to
$$\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{p},\left(\frac{H_{p}}{p}\right)^p\right)-\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{p},\left(\frac{H_{p/k}}{p}\right)^p\right)$$
So you will need to estimate those quantities involving Harmonic numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the usual notation $H_m:=\sum_{i=1}^m\frac1i$, and $0\leqslant 1-e^{-x}\leqslant x$ for $x\geqslant 0$, we have $$0\leqslant H_p-H_{p/k}-\int_{H_{p/k}}^{H_p}e^{-(x/p)^p}\,dx=\int_{H_{p/k}}^{H_p}\big(1-e^{-(x/p)^p}\big)dx\leqslant(H_p/p)^p(H_p-H_{p/k}),$$ and it remains to use $\lim\limits_{p\to\infty}(H_p-H_{p/k})=\ln k$ and $\lim\limits_{p\to\infty} H_p/p=0$.

Comment: It's nice and short ! Thanks !

Comment: I accept it as a twin of words proof .

Answer (score 0):

Hint : we have with the same constraint :

### $$\int_{\sum_{i=1}^{\frac{p}{k}}\frac{1}{i}}^{\sum_{i=1}^{p}\frac{1}{i}}e^{-\frac{x}{p}}dx<\int_{\sum_{i=1}^{\frac{p}{k}}\frac{1}{i}}^{\sum_{i=1}^{p}\frac{1}{i}}e^{-\left(\frac{x}{p}\right)^{p}}dx<\int_{\sum_{i=1}^{\frac{p}{k}}\frac{1}{i}}^{\sum_{i=1}^{p}\frac{1}{i}}e^{-\frac{x}{p^{p}}}dx$$

Now integrate and use the squeeze theorem as @Metamorphy .